# implementing ng-if directive inside md-table

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to use ng-if inside my md-table but I'm getting the error:

```
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with *
```

Here is my code for the template

```
<md-row *cdkRowDef="let row;  columns: displayedColumns" (click)="viewNarrative(row)">
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" *ngIf="!(authService.isAdmin())">
    <button md-button (click)="viewNarrative(row)"><md-icon>toc</md-icon> Narrative</button>
    <button md-button (click)="editDemographics(row)"><md-icon>edit</md-icon> Demographics</button>
    <button md-button (click)="confirmDelete(row, $event)" style="line-height:normal"><md-icon>delete</md-icon> Delete</button>
  </md-cell>
</md-row>
```

when I remove the `*cdkCellDef="let row"` directive I get the error: `ERROR Error: No provider for CdkColumnDef!`
so how can I implement the `ng-if` directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using two structural directives with an asterisk syntax on one element. You need to unwrap one of them. The following should work:

```
  <ng-template [ngIf]="!(authService.isAdmin())">
      <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
        <button md-button (click)="viewNarrative(row)"><md-icon>toc</md-icon> Narrative</button>
        <button md-button (click)="editDemographics(row)"><md-icon>edit</md-icon> Demographics</button>
        <button md-button (click)="confirmDelete(row, $event)" style="line-height:normal"><md-icon>delete</md-icon> Delete</button>
      </md-cell>
  </ng-template>
```

Or simply move `ngIf` to the `ng-container`:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!(authService.isAdmin())">
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like:

This allows you to have the mat-cell and an *ngIf too

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="isActive">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Active </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <mat-icon *ngIf="element.isActive;else notactive;">done</mat-icon>
    <ng-template #notactive><mat-icon>clear</mat-icon></ng-template>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply *ngIf outside md-cell, like this.

```
<md-row *cdkRowDef="let row;  columns: displayedColumns" (click)="viewNarrative(row)">
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">
    <button md-button (click)="viewNarrative(row)"  *ngIf="!(authService.isAdmin())"><md-icon>toc</md-icon> Narrative</button>
    <button md-button (click)="editDemographics(row)" *ngIf="!(authService.isAdmin())"><md-icon>edit</md-icon> Demographics</button>
  </md-cell>
</md-row>
```